# How can i solve error when drawing image in emu8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I have 8086 code for drawing img file. I can use it in dosbox but when it comes to run in emu8086, I got this error

```
    unknown opcode skipped:0F
    not 8086 instruction - not supported yet.
```

This error occurs in readdata function after running ret command. I tried to understand what caused to this error but I couldn't. I just want to know how can i solve it.

Error's screenshot[image]

This is the image i tried to draw : [drivelink](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CkfU8yCwA_Gkbsm-IRshZYuHIOtkuBbn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That sounds like you corrupted the stack. Verify the return address is not overwritten. You seem to be allocating large enough buffer and reading that many bytes with `DS` set up properly so that looks correct.

Comment: Why did you remove the code from the question? Nobody can help you without it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...understand what caused to this error...

The code segment gets overwritten by data, followed by a `ret` instruction returning to a place that no longer contains a valid instruction that emu8086 can recognize.

The DS segment register contains 0714h and, holding 0715h, the CS segment register follows just 16 bytes after that. The .Data section is not setup correctly. I suspect that the question mark in `roseFilehandle DW ?` is the culpritt!

Based on the address that emu8086 assigned to the *roseData* buffer (8), I suggest you rewrite the .Data section like:

```
.Data

roseWidth EQU 200
roseHeight EQU 195

roseFilename   DB 'rose.img', 0
roseData       DB roseWidth*roseHeight dup(0)
roseFilehandle DW 0
```

You might also want to enlarge the stack to a more realistic size: `.Stack 256`.

For maximum compatibility with existing BIOSes, you should not use BX to loop over the image data, use SI instead and set BH=0 to select display page 0.

```
  mov  bh, 0
  mov  si, OFFSET roseData
drawLoop:
```

Comment: I changed the .data section as you wrote. Stack size is set to 256. Also all BX in the code changed with SI and i got this error : Input redirection is not supported yet! INT 21h/9h should be used instead. refer to interrupt reference. Did i made any mistakes? Error for ReadData 's INT 21H

Comment: @mert You have probably changed a couple of BX's too many! Those related to the filehandle must stay as they were. In the original code, I counted 3 uses of BX that should have been changed into SI.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I went too far :) But this time filehandle caused error. This is the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/8teDOog

Comment: @mert The original problem with the data section that is too small is still there! Try to put the `.Data` section **below** the `.Code` section.

Comment: Knowing that emu8086 is rather buggy software, it certainly could help to turn your program into the .COM format (`Model .Tiny`)

Comment: Yes, I know. I need to make some adjustments. I will post it again. Dont worry : ) Thanks for your help